# Secure POST request from NodeJS to Node/Express hangs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https

I'm using the following to send POST data to a secure nodejs server:

File: main.js

```
    var strdata = JSON.stringify({"data":"thisdata"});

    var options = {
        host: '192.168.1.63',
        port: 3001,
        path: '/saveconfig',
        method: 'POST',
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        requestCert: true,
        agent: false,
        
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(strdata)
        }   
        
    };

    
    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
        console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
        console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
        });
    });
    
    console.log(req.write(strdata));
    console.log(req.end());

    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });

    req.on('finish', function() {
        console.log("finished request");
    });
```

In an otherwise functional expressjs server, these are the appropriate snippets:

File: app.js

```
app.post('/saveconfig', function() { 
    data.saveconfig; console.log("received request"); } );

app.get('/getconfig', data.getconfig);
```

File: data.js

```
exports.saveconfig = function(req, res) {
console.log("saveing config");
        
res.send(200);
res.end();

};

exports.getconfig = function(req, res) {
res.send("get OK");
}
```

With app.js running on the server (Ubuntu), I run main.js from the client (Windows 7). req.write and req.end execute and "finished request" logs to the console, but the request callback never fires.

On the server in app.js, the app.post event fires and logs "received request" to the console. But "saving config" never logs to the console. Only after I kill (^C) main.js, express then logs to the console "POST /saveconfig".

I know I'm missing something simple, but I've read dozens of coding examples and you can likely gather from my snippet, I've tried everything I can find or think of. I'd guess the request isn't finishing, but I don't know why. What is missing to get "exports.saveconfig" to fire?

*additional information*

**The answer posted below fixed my problem. Because I'm new to stackoverflow, I can't post my own answer, but here's the rest of the story...**

I appreciate your help. Being still new to JavaScript, I found I can learn a lot about an object by converting it to string. I was originally attempting to convert the req parameter to a string *using a custom function*. I just discovered it was apparently running into an endless loop after using JSON.stringify instead.

The code looked something like this:

```
exports.saveconfig = function (db) {
    return function(req, res) {
        console.log("saving config");
    
        console.log(mymodule.serialize(req));
    
        res.end("OK");
    
        console.log(req.body);
   };
};
```

I would have thought the above code should have logged the following to the console- even if the serialize method was in an endless loop:

> POST /saveconfig
>
> saving config
>
> [nothing because of the endless loop]

Instead I got:

> saving config
>
> connections property is deprecated. Use getConnections() method

Being new to JavaScript, I assumed something was wrong with the request, the server, or some plumbing in-between. Of course, then the debugging code I added (along with my ignorance of JS) compounded the problem.

Changing

```
app.post('/saveconfig', function() { 
data.saveconfig; console.log("received request"); } );
```

to

```
app.post('/saveconfig', datarts.saveconfig);
```

and removing the endless loop fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in you're app.js. You use `data.saveConfig` inside your callback without calling it. The right way would be

```
app.post('/saveconfig', function(req,res) { 
    data.saveconfig(req, res); 
    console.log("received request"); 
});

app.get('/getconfig', data.getconfig);
```

or (I assume the `console.log` is just for debugging purposes):

```
app.post('/saveconfig', data.saveconfig);

app.get('/getconfig', data.getconfig);
```

You could do your `console.log()` inside your `data.saveconfig` method if you want to go with the second example.